# How to disable xhtml validation in telerik rad editor?.

Tags: telerik

How can I disable the XHTML validation in Telerik rad editor?

I know that for disabling scripts, I have used the following:

In `page_load` I have following code:

```
radEditor.AllowScripts = true; 
radEditor.DisableFilter(Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters.RemoveScripts);
```

But how do I disable the XHTML validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable XHTML Validation by using the following code:

```
radEditor.DisableFilter(Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters.ConvertToXhtml);
```

Comment: This was helpful in getting an older (2011) version of RadEditor working somewhat reasonably in modern browsers. Thanks.  Without this toggling between design/html view would generate extra line breaks.